# A disabled user still show in search result and manage user profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

We have a disabled account that shows in search results. So we checked CA> Manage User Profile and the user still exist (note we implemented userAccountControl Bit on equals 2) and this is only affecting a single account. I suggested to do a full profile import, but they don't want to do it.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there another way to fix the issue? I was thinking delete the account from CA > Manage User Profile, but not sure if that would resolve the issue.
2. Is there a significant impact on the SharePoint servers to do a full profile import?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the connection filter then you need to run the full import.

If user is active at the time of import and disabled after that...again you need to run the profile sync either incremental or full.

To remove from people search once profile sync completed then run the people search crawl to remove it from search result as well.

Why you hesitant to run full import? Their is no impact on user but may be some performance hit if you run it in peak hours. I would run full import at off peak hours and over the weekends. It is good practice to run full sync once a month.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We did not change the filter, and the issue only affect a single user and user profile sync runs incremental import every day.I would like to run full import but I get a push back and they want me to fix it without starting a full import. I am with you that the performance hit won't be an issue if we do it after hours, but they want me to dig deeper into the issue.

Comment: did you try to delete the User profile from Profile store? simply delete it and then run the full People search crawl...